# How to track url redirects in .Net Application?

Tags: asp.net

When I type http://example.com/load/ in my browser and press ENTER, this website redirects me to several URL's and then I finally landed on http://example.com/load/3/.

These redirection happens at the website end, and I finally landed on this last URL. I know by using firebug or fiddler I can get all these related url's.

But I need to get all these related URL's through my .Net application. Because iam working on an application which should do all the jobs as firebug does. thereafter I need to check the status of each URL's from my application.

Need help to get this code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to track these url using your .NET application you can use

HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property.

Another suggestion would be using

http_referer ex(string referer = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];)

Take a glance at Page.PreviousPage Property too.

Comment: II have heard about HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property , but hadn't yet tried it out. Looks like it should solve the  question.Thanks for the tip!

Comment: UrlReferrer gaves me URL of previous calling page , not the child url's. My question is how can i get all the child URL's related to a URL which is loading. like the child url's we get using firebug.